# Need to send an email to customers in a journey with specified intervals of time in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Need to send an email to customers in a journey with specified intervals of time in marketing cloud.

Here if a journey is activated and emails are triggered and it has a wait time of 15 days for the second email between these gaps we had updated my data extension then the second email should be triggered according to the updated data extension

I was wondering whether this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the current release (208). Lookout for the 209 - 210 releases as they might introduce something that would help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if decision split is configured on Contact Data rather than Journey Data. Every time a decision split is configured, after waiting at the wait activity, the value of the required attribute for that contact is picked up from the updated Data Extension.